# Ruby - Verify hash key exists

Tags: ruby, hash, nested, verify

I'm having a problem working with a nested hash and hoping to get some assistance.  The data I'm working with looks like the following:

```
    => {"searchresults"=>
  {"request"=>{"address"=>"10 Tiverton Ln", "citystatezip"=>"28803"},
   "message"=>{"text"=>"Request successfully processed", "code"=>"0"},
   "response"=>
    {"results"=>
      {"result"=>
        {"zpid"=>"5620805"}}
```

I'm trying to grab specific information from the hash.  The problem I'm having is:  If the hash key isn't present, it throws an error and kills my script.

To re-mediate this issue, I figured I would just verify the key presence beforehand, however, my check doesn't appear to be working properly.  I'm using the "key?" method, but I'm obviously doing something wrong since in my verification (when the key is there) results in a "false" back from Ruby.

```
hash["searchresults"]["response"]["results"]["result"]["zpid"]
=> "5620805"
hash.key?("searchresults""response""results""result""zpid")
=> false
```

(NOTE:  I realized the last input was just a concatenated string based on comment, but can't get any combination to work, see below-towards bottom of post)

What is the best way to get around errors when querying for a hash key that doesn't exist?  If the "key?" method is the proper way to go about it, can someone please point me in the right direction of where my error is.

---

Added info based on responses.  I'm using the following version of ruby

```
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
```

I was finally able to understand the dig method syntax thanks to comments.Everything is working as I need...THANK YOU!

```
hash.dig("searchresults", "response", "results", "result", "zpid")
    => "5620805"
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you working with? Newer ones have [`Hash#dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Hash.html#method-i-dig) that might be of use to you.

Comment: Readers cannot use your example to test solutions because it is not a valid Ruby object. Here you've given part of hash, yet it would be very simple to make it a valid hash. Also, whenever you give an example, please show your desired output and assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `h = { "searchresults"=>...}`). The latter allows readers to refer to those variable (here `h`) in answers and comments without having to define them. Also, please edit out `pry(main)> `. As well as being distractive, every reader who cuts and pastes that code will have to remove it if you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
h = { "searchresults"=>
        { "request" =>{ "address"=>"10 Tiverton Ln", "citystatezip"=>"28803" },
          "message" =>{ "text"=>"Request successfully processed", "code"=>"0" },
          "response"=>{ "results"=>{
                                     "result"=>{ "zpid"=>"5620805" }
                                   }
                      }
        }
    }
```

As @muistooshort pointed out in a comment, [Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) can be used here if you are using Ruby v2.3+.

```
h.dig("searchresults")
  #=> {"request"=>{"address"=>"10 Tiverton Ln", "citystatezip"=>"28803"},
  #    "message"=>{"text"=>"Request successfully processed", "code"=>"0"},
  #    "response"=>{"results"=>{"result"=>{"zpid"=>"5620805"}}}} 
h.dig("searchresults", "response")
  #=> {"results"=>{"result"=>{"zpid"=>"5620805"}}}
h.dig("searchresults", "response", "results")
  #=> {"result"=>{"zpid"=>"5620805"}} 
h.dig("searchresults", "response", "results", "result")
  #=> {"zpid"=>"5620805"} 
h.dig("searchresults", "response", "results", "result", "zpid")
  #=> "5620805"

h.dig("searchresults", "cat", "results")
  #=> nil
h.dig("searchresults", "response", "results", "result", "dog")
  #=> nil
```

For earlier versions of Ruby you can use [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`).

```
def my_dig(h, *keys)
  keys.reduce(h) { |g,k| g && g[k] }
end

my_dig(h, "searchresults")
  #=> {"request"=>{"address"=>"10 Tiverton Ln", "citystatezip"=>"28803"},
  #    "message"=>{"text"=>"Request successfully processed", "code"=>"0"},
  #    "response"=>{"results"=>{"result"=>{"zpid"=>"5620805"}}}} 
my_dig(h, "searchresults", "response")
  #=> {"results"=>{"result"=>{"zpid"=>"5620805"}}}
my_dig(h, "searchresults", "response", "results")
  #=> {"result"=>{"zpid"=>"5620805"}} 
my_dig(h, "searchresults", "response", "results", "result")
  #=> {"zpid"=>"5620805"} 
my_dig(h, "searchresults", "response", "results", "result", "zpid")
  #=> "5620805" 

my_dig(h, "searchresults", "cat", "results")
  #=> nil 
my_dig(h, "searchresults", "response", "results", "result", "zpid", "dog")
  #=> nil
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I've added detail to my original post to hopefully clear things up.  Using your info from above, I still seem to be getting errors.  pry(main)> hash.dig("searchresults", "response", "results", "result", "zpid")
=> "5620805"
pry(main)> hash.key?(hash.dig("searchresults", "response", "results", "result", "zpid"))
=> false

Comment: Consider `h = {:a=>{:c=>{:d=>1}, :b=>2}}` and you want the value at h[:a][:b][:d]`. Here h[:a][:b][:d] #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass` (because `h[:a][:b] #=> nil`, so `nil[:d]` raises the exception). Yet all three keys, `:a`, `:b` and `:d` are in the hash. Clearly, you can't just determine if individual keys are present. My answer returns the desired result when all keys are present, in the correct order, and `nil` otherwise. Isn't that what you want to do? It's just as much work to find if all keys are present in the right order, so why bother with that?